# How to change amount variable is incremented by in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

!NO JQUERY!

Ok, so I am making a game for my friends based on cookie clicker game from years ago and my issue is I want to increase what the clicks are incremented by when I click a multiplier button.

Basically, when the user reaches 100 clicks and if they click on the multiplier button it will increase the increment by 1.

The cpcm function `function cpcm(){cl1ck5m = 1;}` will increase cl1ck5m by 1 when the user clicks the multiplier button.  I want to add this value to the main increment `total = cl1ck +=1;` in the `function cl1ckm8() {}` only if the user clicks the multiplier button when they reach 100 clicks.

I dont know how I would do this.

```
var cl1ck5 = 0;
var total = 0;
var cl1ck5m = 0;
var rotated = false;

window.alert("H3lp C00ki3 Man3st3r!\nCan y0u h3lp C00ki3 Man3st3r c0ll3ct c00ki3s?");

function cl1ckm8() {
  total = cl1ck +=1;
  document.getElementById('cl1ckC0unt').innerHTML = total;
  if (cl1ck5 == 90) {
    var div = document.getElementById('butt');
    var deg = rotated ? 0 : 90;
    var msg = document.getElementById("ache");

    msg.innerHTML = "nineD d3gr33s";
    div.style.transform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
  }

  if (cl1ck5 == 100) {
   var div = document.getElementById('cpcbutt');
   div.innerHTML = "1";
  }
}

function cpcm(){
   cl1ck5m = 1;
}
```

Comment: so create a `var multiplier = 1;` then change it as the game runs?

Comment: You can put the desired behavior into words. What is stopping you from putting it into code?

Comment: I know I can write it in words it is just I dont know how to add `cl1ck5m = 1;` in the `function cl1ckm8() {}`.  Because when I tried adding it in earlier it only added the multiplier once and then it went back to 1 per click

Comment: And it is only supposed to this at 100 clicks and only if the user clicks the button which triggers the `function cpcm(){}` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.  Thanks for any help.

I simply put the multiplier in place of the 1 in `total = cl1ck +=1;` like `total = cl1ck +=cl1ckm;`.  I was trying to avoid this way to find other ways of doing it but this works best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but anyway...

```
var multiplierButtonClicked = false;

document.getElementById("multiplier").onclick = function(){
       if (cl1ck5 >= 100)
            multiplierButtonClicked=true;
}

function cl1ckm8() 
{
    total = cl1ck +=1;

    if (multiplierButtonClicked)
       total += cl1ck5m;

    //...
}

function cpcm(){
   if (multiplierButtonClicked)
      cl1ck5m += 1;
}
```

Comment: http://www.sydluce.tk/ded.html Heres a link to what im working on.  Basically when the user reaches 100 clicks the button in the lower left corner will increase the the increment to 2 per click if they press on it.